# Which of the following sets of vectors span R^3?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

[image]

Can anyone explain how to do this? Usually when the question gives a vector and asks whether it is in span with some other vectors I put them in a matrix and calculate the determinant and so on but with this question type I am not really sure

Answer (score 1):

To span $\mathbb{R^3}$ you need 3 linearly independent vectors. You can determine if the 3 vectors provided are linearly independent by calculating the determinant, as stated in your question.

If you have 3 linearly independent vectors that are each elements of $\mathbb{R^3}$, the vectors span $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: So I can use three vectors such as (0,0,1) , (0,1,0) , (1,0,0) and all of them has to give a determinant of zero, is that right?

Comment: (0,0,1), (0,1,0), and (1,0,0) do span $\mathbb{R^3}$ because they are linearly independent (which we know because the determinant of the corresponding matrix is not 0) and there are three of them. For the possibilities listed in your question, find the determinants of the corresponding matrices. If the determinant is not zero, the vectors must be linearly independent. If you have three linearly independent vectors, they will span $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Option (i) is out, since we can't span $\Bbb R^3$ with less than $\dim \Bbb R^3 = 3$ vectors. If you have exactly $\dim \Bbb R^3 = 3$ vectors, they will span $\Bbb R^3$ if and only if they are linearly independent -- for this reason it suffices to check determinants. Compute $$(ii) = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\-1 & -4 & 2 \end{vmatrix}\quad\mbox{and}\quad (iii) = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ -1 & -4 & -2\end{vmatrix}.$$One should select options (ii) and/or (iii) in the statement of the problem if and only if the corresponding determinants above are nonzero.